# How to create a mapping between types

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a library to query [Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/).

I have a type class

```
class GoogleMapsRequest a
```

which defines some function needed to build the URL and a function

```
queryAPI :: (FromJSON x, GoogleMapsRequest r) => r -> GoogleMaps x
```

(`GoogleMaps` is a simple MonadStack to get some config values etc.). Now I only need to define some data types and instances for each web service. For example I created the geocode service:

```
data GeocodeRequest = GeocodeAddress Text

data GeocodeResponse = ...

instance GoogleMapsRequest GeocodeRequest where
  ...

geocode :: GeocodeRequest -> GoogleMaps GeocodeResponse
geocode = queryAPI
```

My problem here is that I need to wrap `queryAPI` or specify the response type explicit although the response type is basically clear and I can do stuff like:

```
geocode :: GeocodeRequest -> GoogleMaps Text
```

that compiles but will always fail.

So here comes my question: Is there any cool feature or maybe an obvious solution that I don't see to get this mapping between the request and response types?

I tried to make a `MultiParamTypeClass`:

```
class GoogleMapsRequest a b
queryAPI :: (FromJSON x, GoogleMapsRequest r x) => r -> GoogleMaps x
```

but I'm not sure if this is the right approach and I always get some 'Could not deduce' errors form the use of the function to build the urls.

Thanks!

Comment: Although not exactly an answer, my suggestion would be to not use a type class like `GoogleMapsRequest` or `GoogleMaps` if they can't obey any property or laws. Looking at your example it seems that just defining some types and operating some functions on them should solve your problem.

Comment: `class GoogleMapsRequest a b` will not allow the compiler to deduce the result type from the input type. You likely want to enable functional dependencies and have `class GoogleMapsRequest a b | a -> b`

Comment: Although a type class is not really needed as @Sibi mentioned, functional dependencies did the trick when using a multiparam type class. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you want to have a function `queryAPI :: a -> M b` where the types `a` and `b` are related. You want to have a list of "mappings" between individual types. In other words:

```
queryAPI :: MapsRequest -> M MapsResponse
queryAPI :: GeocodeRequest -> M GeocodeResponse
...
```

There are ways to accomplish this. But they would be confusing for your users; in particular, Haddock would not indicate the actual type of each overloaded function.

Could you simply have different functions for each API?

```
queryMaps :: MapsRequest -> M MapsResponse
queryGeocode :: GeocodeRequest -> M GeocodeResponse
...
```

In other words, set aside typeclasses entirely. Many people, including me, discourage using typeclasses simply to overload function names. (People talk about "laws" like the `Functor` laws; there are also situations like `FromJSON` where you need to use typeclasses to deal with recursive types.)

*Edit*: As you rightly observed, this is mainly a point about user interface, i.e. the exported API. How you implement it is up to you; wrapping a generic `queryAPI` function is idiomatic. Without having thought about it much, your use case doesn't seem to cry out for type classes in the implementation, but rather using, as you pointed out, generic data types internally ("stringly-typed", as the pun goes; `queryAPI` might be `ApiRequest -> M ByteString`) and then exporting a more-strongly-typed public API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You understood me right. Your arguments sound reasonable, especially the point that this may be a bit confusing for users. However, what do you think about using the type class only internally and exporting different functions for each API, that just wrap `queryAPI`? Is that a bad practice?

Comment: I changed everything to use a generic data type instead of a type class. Seems to be a better way.

Comment: Using internal typeclasses is fine as long as it actually helps you and the public interface conceals it. Is your situation that you have a certain amount of code for establishing a connection, authentication, etc. that doesn't actually involve the data itself? If so, it's perfectly valid to have "weakly typed" core functions using `ByteString`s or whatever, and then wrap it up with individual functions with more specific types. A bit like reading a file (generic data) versus parsing it (generic data to specific types).

Answer (score 0):

In GHC, Multiparameter type classes or associated (type/data) families will do what you ask.  If you decide not to use a type class, you might still use a (type/data) family.

For MPTCs you'd do something like:

```
class GMR req resp | req -> resp where
    queryAPI :: req -> GoogleMaps resp

instance GMR GeocodeRequest GeocodeResponse where
    ...
```

For associated type families, you'd do something like:

```
class GoogleMapsRequest req where
    type Response req

queryApi :: (GoogleMapsRequest req, FromJSON (Response req)) => req -> GoogleMaps (Response req)

instance GoogleMapsRequest GeocodeRequest where
    type Response GoogleMapsRequest = GeocodeResponse
```

Comment: With your first solution, fundeps would be required for inference to work. The second solution has a few problems. I would have expected `type Response` to be an error, but it's not; you just can't write more than one instance... (It should probably be `Response req`.) Furthermore, `queryApi` almost certainly needs to be a member of the class, for reasons that become clear in trying to actually use `Response req` in its implementation; `queryApi` can't do case analysis on the its own type variable `req`.

Comment: @ChristianConkle Fixed some of it; I don't use either GHC feature often myself, so I'm sort of surprised I got the answer as close as I did.  I mainly moved `queryApi` out of the TC to show that it could be done.  But yes, either queryApi or some other "lower-level" function (e.g. `getResponseRaw :: req -> IO ByteString`) would need to be in the TC.